# A writable disk is required. : (-69772). NVMe SSD Upgrade

Tags: macos, ssd, pci-express, imac, nvme

I have iMac Late 2013 model and it didn't have SSD installed by default so I have decided to upgrade it with NVMe SSD.

For this purpose, I have purchased 2 devices:

1. [M.2 NVME SSD Convert Adapter Card](https://www.amazon.in/Syscom-Convert-Adapter-Upgraded-2013-2017/dp/B08THTBQPH/ref=sr_1_10)
2. [Kingston 1TB A2000 M.2 2280 Nvme Internal SSD](https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-Internal-2000MB-SA2000M8-1000G/dp/B07VXC9QMH/ref=sr_1_3)

All setups got completed properly and worked for around 1 week without any issue.
One day I decided to transfer my whole work data to an installed SSD because it was almost empty.

During this copying process around 120GB of data get transferred but suddenly it gets stuck with some error.
This is my current situation of installed NVMe SSD, I have recorded a video for this and uploaded it on Google Drive:

[NVMe SSD Failed Video Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xWMADCOoNlbiRMwFVg7q3-fdN2qpHM3R/view?usp=sharing)

It is stopped me to write something on it so I have decided to format this but it giving me this kind of error message:
[image]

I have read different posts related to similar issues but everyone is struggling so I have decided to create a new post with all my recent information.

Adapter and SSD both I have purchased new from Amazon.
I don't know why this kind of problem occurred whether it's because of heavy data transfer in one shot.

Please share your opinion so I can solve this problem.

Comment: Whether this firmware update can help me in this - https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ksm-firmware-update

Comment: Doubtful.  The only possible change would be, "Fixed an issue that might cause the drive to become unresponsive on Linux systems", but that does not appear to be the problem you face.  You also have not specified what version of the firmware the drive has currently.

Comment: How can I check the current firmware version? Because Kingston does not have their SSD Manager software for the Mac OS and at present NVMe SSD inside my iMac

Comment: I have used it for 1 week and then after it got stopped working so I was surprised what went wrong!!